# Strange sort jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jqgrid

I have issue with sort in my jqGrid.

This is my jqGrid.

All columns sort normal. But only title column sort some strange. How i can resolve this issue?

Get data from sharepoint online 2013

Comment: You didn't post the data.

Comment: What is your question? can you explain it please, I couldn't understand it. what is "title column sort some strange". OK I see what you mean, can you post more data?

Comment: Sorry, i had a mistake. Wrong sort in column with name "Task Name" and data in 2 screenshots which i add in my post.

Comment: When i use asc sort in first place i have a record which start from "W" but in my list a have record which start from "A". And i need normal ASC sort in my grid. Say please which data do you need?

Comment: @AlexYatsenko: You use `datatype: 'jsonstring'`, but no `datastr` with the input data? Why? Typical problem with sorting TreeGrid is wrong value for `parent` column of the root elements. So the input data are really required.

Comment: @Oleg I update my post and add method which add data to jqGrid

Comment: @AlexYatsenko: I posted the answer. It it not solve your problem you should post **the test data** (the `_taskItems`) which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not good to place HTML fragments like `var taskTitle = '<a href="'...` in the grid. Instead of that one should use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) for the `"taskTitle"` column. The difference is very easy to explain. The current code interpret `'taskTitle'` as **string** during sorting. So the URL from `src` attribute is more important as the text of `<a>` which see the user.

By usage of [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) you provides `formatter` and [unformat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting) callbacks which will be called by jqGrid to display the data in the cell and to get the data from the cell. So You can choose which data you use for sorting . If the custom formatters still not solve your problem you can define `sorttype` as function. It's helpful to replace the cell data to another data which should be used for sorting only.